# Case email attachment

Tags: lightning

While sending an email from case and adding attachment to that email in Classic we have a filter to show attachments only from this case, but in Lightning I can't locate such filter. It is important filter as we can’t search for all attachments to just send this email. Is there anything I am missing or does anyone know a workaround to filter list of attachment by case I am sending email from?

**Classic**

[image]

**Lightning**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, no, the filter hasn't been replicated in Lightning (yet).  The idea is under product team review though:

> [Select Files from Related Record when composing Send Email](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CNxjQAG)

Until this is available, here are some possible, if less-desireable, options:

- Use a trigger to append the Case Number to the attachment's name. Searching for the case number in the composition interface will bring up the associated files.
- Write your own custom lightning component to replace the standard email action
- Check out some of the apps on the AppExchange that replace the standard email action.  I haven't seen any that are Lightning-ready, but...  here's a start:

  - [Lightside Power Tools](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFoy9UAD)
  - [Send an Email Plus](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5kQJEAZ)

Answer (score 0):

This is because Lightning uses files and not attachments, there is a relatively easy way to fix this going forward there is an option in salesforce on the email to case to save attachments as files.

You can find the exact way to implement this functionality [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_cases_e2c_attachments.htm)

You can also find some information on the why it is not searchable [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Attachments-are-not-returned-in-Lightning-Experience-search&language=en_US&type=1)

Hope that helps,

Comment: I can see attachments in a file window. That is not a problem. Problem is I can't filter those file by Case same as in classic.